# Selecting XML nodes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
        <Car>
            <BMW>
                <Price>100</Price>
            </BMW>
        </Car>
        <Car>
            <TOYOTA>
                <Price>100</Price>
            </TOYOTA>
        </Car>
```

and I want to transform it in text like that:

```
    <xsl:if test="Car/BMW">
        <xsl:value-of select="Car/BMW/Price" />§BMW§<xsl:value-of select="'&#x000a;'"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="Car/TOYOTA">
        <xsl:value-of select="Car/TOYOTA/Price" />§TOYOTA§<xsl:value-of select="'&#x000a;'"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

The question is if I can do the same without the if conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is one row for each Price element, with the second bit of text taken from the name of that element's parent:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Car/*/Price">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '§', local-name(..), '§&#xa;')/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, I didn't know about the function local-name